# RequestParameter in view_email_url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to send extra parameters to view_email_url and then pick them up and use them on the web version of the email? I would like to do this so I can perform different actions, such as display a pop up or play a video.

It should be as simple as the code below, but unfortunately RequestParameter doesn't seem to work on the VAWP:

```
%%[

if _MessageContext == "VAWP" then
set @parameter = RequestParameter("parameter")

]%%

<span>The parameter is: %%=v(@parameter)=%%</span>

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you are making it more difficult than it needs to be.

This sounds like a use case for the personalization string `%%_messagecontext%%`. Like you have, but instead of setting parameters - just put the content inside of it.

You use a conditional surrounding the content you want only on the VAWP version and it will then only be displayed on VAWP version.

E.g.

```
%%[ IF _messagecontext == "VAWP" THEN ]%%

     <p>**MY VIDEO HTML CONTENT**</p>

%%[ ENDIF]%%
```

or if you want to store externally, say inside of a DE or something, you can do it like this:

```
%%[ IF _messagecontext == "VAWP" THEN
    SET @button = LOOKUP('contentDE', 'button', 'key', @key)
]%%

     %%=TreatAsContent(@button)=%%

%%[ ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something to the stuff that Gortonington has already said:

The URL Parameter from Emails consists out of 8 different parameters which will form the hash of the `view_email_url`:

These are

> - j = JobID
> - m = MID (Business Unit)
> - ls = ListSubscriber
> - l = ListID
> - S = SubscriberID
> - jb = Job BatchID
> - ju = JobUrlID
> - n i am not certain but i believe its a rownumber or sth like that.

Example (i changed some stuff):

```
j=105891&m=123456789&ls=35631528&l=358&s=38629805&jb=1&ju=1637251&n=6002
```

You can find many of these inside [**personalization strings**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5).

Because these hashes are a fixed implementation of salesforce you won't be able to insert more parameters, just do it like Gortonington.